# Swift - how can I archive array?

Tags: swift

I have an array of stings. Is it possible to archive it using NSKeyedArchiver or NSCoding and then assign to variable of type NSData ? I need this to store my array in CoreData.

Comment: What kind of data is in your array?

Comment: Strings. Captions for photos.